# Workaround on FileReference.save() dialog box

Tags: apache-flex, flash, adobe, flexbuilder, flash-builder

Im still new in Flex and currently working on capturing a flash game into a flv video file. Im using FileReference.save() to write the captured file in the user's system. It is working as of now but not the way I want it to be.

Is there a way to bypass or automate the save dialog box when invoking the save() api of fileReference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, no. This would be violation of Flash security model. Flash application cannot write to disk unless user allows it.

Comment: This is correct.  Flash in the browser must obey typical browser sandbox rules.  If you want to get out of the browser sandbox then run the app on the desktop using Adobe AIR.